# Drag animation on cell content inside/outside cell containers

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a Table like this:

[image: Table]

Note that each table cell has a kind of container(Gray) where the content (White) inside can be moved to another container or ordered inside the same container.

If a container doesn't have a content, it's gray and it has a minimum size, but you can add as many content as you want inside it and the container will expand to accommodate the new content, or contract when a container is removed from it.

You can move a content from one container to another.

Inside a container the user can also reorder the content just like a regular UITableView.

I don't know how to get this effect, I thought of adding a UITableView inside each container, but you cannot drag a table from one UITableView to another. So I'm considering a UICollectionView, but then I'll not have all "free" UITableView drag/sort animations which can be quite cumbersome to implement. (Just the sort ordering alone has a lot of details involved like sorting everything while the user drags the content on the table).

I'm wondering if anyone has an idea of how to implement this leveraging as much as possible from the iOS SDK.
Thanks.